# Create ListView.builder from StreamBuilder with ISAR Database

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, stream-builder, flutter-isar

I am trying to create a `ListView.builder` from `StreamBuilder` in Flutter.

`TodoList` class:

```dart
import 'package:isar/isar.dart';

part 'todo_list.g.dart';

@Collection()
class TodoList {
  Id id = Isar.autoIncrement;
  late String todoTitle;
}
```

`IsarService` class:

```dart
class IsarService {
  IsarService() {
    db = openDB();
  }

  late Future<Isar> db;

  // Return IsarDB, if not found, then create
  Future<Isar> openDB() async {
    if (Isar.instanceNames.isEmpty) {
      return await Isar.open(
        [TodoListSchema],
        inspector: true,
      );
    }
    return Future.value(Isar.getInstance());
  }

  Stream<List<TodoList>> listenToTodoList() async* {
    final isar = await db;
    yield* isar.todoLists.where().watch(fireImmediately: true);
  }
}
```

`ListScreen` widget:

```dart
class ListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListScreen(this.service, {super.key});

  final IsarService service;

  @override
  State<ListScreen> createState() => _ListScreenState();
}

class _ListScreenState extends State<ListScreen> {
  // Text Controller
  final _textController = TextEditingController();
  final service = IsarService();
  // Let's build List Title from snapshot
  final List<TodoList> _todoList = [];

  // Root widget of the class
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // List Screen Body Section
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: service.listenToTodoList(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            AlertDialog(
              content: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            _todoList.add(snapshot.data); // Error happen in this line
          }
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

```bash
The argument type 'List<TodoList>?' can't be assigned to the
parameter type 'TodoList'.
```

I'm trying to assign the snapshot data in `final List<TodoList> _todoList = [];` and use them in `ListView.builder`

Comment: could you share your `TodoList` class? Basically the list element should be of type `TodoList` and you've to convert the `snapshot.data` (of type `Map<String,dynamic>`) to `TodoList`

Comment: Kindly share your `IsarService` class

Comment: `snapshot.data` return data from the `Stream` data. But you're trying to add that returned data through the `_todoList.add(snapshot.data)` and that's why the error is throwing

Comment: @Delwinn, I've edited my Question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: StreamBuilder(
  stream: service.listenToTodoList(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      AlertDialog(
        content: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
      );
    } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
      final todos = snapshot.data;
      if (todos != null) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: todos.length();
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final todo = todos[index];
            return Text(todo.todoTitle);
          }
        );
      } else {
        return const Center(child: Text('No data found!'));
      }
    }
    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
  ),
);
```